# What is the equivalence in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, data-conversion

In java I am using the following code

```
string value = "b:0001"
```

`byte[] bytes = value.getBytes("US-ASCII");`

Does anyone know the equivalent in Swift 3 but instead of passing to bytes [] pass to Data?

Comment: Are you just trying to get the bytes of a string in ASCII encoding?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1690799-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you Data back:

```
let str = "b:0001"
let bytes = str.data(using: .ascii)!
```

Comment: Thank you. You save my week :)